# Delphi Firemonkey IOS TContextOpenGL.DestroyPixelShader EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, delphi, client, firemonkey, datasnap

I have a up-to-date platform with Delphi XE 2 update 4 and Xcode 4.3.2 on lion.
I download the embarcadero sample 
http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/28786
because I need a valid sample to retrieve datas and picture in a iOS application written in Delphi Firemonkey from a firebird database with a datasnap server (All others links are welcome).
When I try to to launch the client side in Xcode I have permanetly errors

```
procedure TContextOpenGL.DestroyPixelShader(const Shader: TContextShader);    
begin    
  if Valid and (Shader <> 0) and MakeCurrent then    
  glDeleteShader(Shader); <-HERE *****************    
end;
```

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, adress= 0x0).

Does anybody have the same problems ?
How to test the application ?

Thanks and Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means your connection to the DataSnap server didn't work. Been there, done that... Check the connection settings from your client to the server ;-)

Comment: You're right.I didn't think of this error was linked with the on-create event of the form. I move the code of the on create event on a button and the application is running. I must learn more about Delphi Firemonkey debug informations. A lot of thanks.